# How to remove server name from response header in python (SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)

Tags: python, python-3.x, simplehttprequesthandler

i want to remove/change server name

```
  class MyServer(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
       def _setHeader(self):
          self.send_response(200)
          self.send_header('Content-Type','text/html; charset=utf-8')
          self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',"*")
          self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials','true')
          self.send_header('Server','Custom name')
          self.end_headers()
```

[image]

```
self.send_header('Server','Custom name')
```

i tried to change server name
but it's not working

please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Showing "Server name" in response header is security thread  ?.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used it in a while but the server_version field should do the trick.

```
class MyServer(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _setHeader(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.server_version = "Server: NameYouWant"
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        self.end_headers()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not working , is there any another trick ?.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the class variables `server_version` and `sys_version`:

```py
class MyServer(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    server_version = 'MyServer/1.2'
    sys_version = 'MyProgram/3.4'
```

This will produce the header: `Server: MyServer/1.2 MySoftware/3.4`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html